# Can't create product variant through API

Tags: api, product, shopify, variant

Cant seem to create new product variant using shopify api.

This is my code:

```
global  $shopifyClient;

$config['shopify_api_product_price'] = "/admin/products/128671451/variants.json";  

$variant = array 
( 
    'variant' => array ('price' => '3.00', 'option1' => 'test')
); 

if( $shopifyClient == null )
    return;

try{
    $postVariant = $shopifyClient->call('POST', $config['shopify_api_product_price'], $variant);

    return $postVariant;

}catch( ShopifyApiException $e ){
    $e->getMessage();
}
return false;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some more details? What programming language do you use? What is the error the above code raises?